# How do I resolve a WCF Random endpoint not found exception?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, iis

**Issue:**
I have been working on an issue related to WCF endpoint not found exception. We have around 30 WCF services running on an apppool that recycles every night. It has queue size of 1000. All services have `basichttpbinding` with open/close timeout of 1 min and receive timeout of 10 mins. Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7 is used to host the services

**Exception:**

```
Type: EndpointNotFoundException
Details: There was no endpoint listening at https://url.com/WCFServices/LoginService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

**Inner Exception:**

```
Type: System.Net.WebException
Details: The Remote name could not be resolved.
```

**Troubleshooting:**

- Issue occurs randomly throughout the day. Only happening on login service and other services are not affected.
- IIS performance monitoring done and queues are not reaching 1000.
- IIS apppool does not restart in middle of day. It has been configured to recycle at 2 am in night.
- No exception on the server side.
- WCF logging enabled on server and client. Client shows the end point not found exception. No Exceptions on server.

  Image: [image]

Please let me know what we can do about it as I have run out of options.

Comment: What does the InnerException say? When it occurs, does it so for all clients? What do you do to resolve the issue? In what way does the login service differ from the other services?

Comment: Inner exception was not logged yesterday but hopefully in today's logs I will see some inner exceptions. Our system calls the server every 15 mins after logging (telling server that client in alive and gets a new token in background). When the service call fails to retrieve a token from server, a login screen is displayed. Showing login form after 15 mins deceives the purpose or refreshing token in background. Most of the times it works but sometimes it fails! It does not happen on all clients, it happens on some of them and it is quite random.

Comment: All services use same binding configuration: bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_WCF"

Comment: Added inner exception

Comment: Is there any validation in any datacontract at client/ server?

Comment: There is a validator on the server. It should thorw an exception when validation fails but nothing being capture so have ruled that out.

Comment: Sorry my links did not help you... I am curious as to why you aren't using the more secure WS binding for your login service - the WS service will encrypt the user name and password where the BasicHTTP will not.

Comment: We have transport level security and the engineers working on project earlier though it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Given the intermittent nature of the issue, these posts may be relevant:

1. [Intermittent 'the remote name could not be resolved'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601797/intermittent-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved)
2. [ASP.NET Exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'apiconnector.com'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077946/asp-net-exception-the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-apiconnector-com)

Comment: I had a look at both of the links before I posted my question. First one talks about queue length but we have checked, that's not a problem. Second one talks about proxy, but we do not have proxy servers. So, links do not help :(